# How do I use AutoFit when using VLOOKUP to fill a cell?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

With “autofit” set, one is able to let the height or width adjust accordingly to whatever you enter. The cell size should be updated after entering new data.

This is not the case with cells that use the "VLOOKUP" function. The dimensions of the cells stay the same unless you manually hit “autofit height” or “autofit width” again.

My workaround is this code that selects all cells and adjusts the dimensions:

```vb
Cells.Select
Selection.Rows.AutoFit
```

Is this the only way to change the behaviour of Excel (2013 Version)?

Comment: I don't think that it is due to the VLOOKUP-formula. Are these cells set to "wrap text"? If yes: AutoFit indeed doesn't work like expected.

Comment: Side Note: `Select` is not needed here and can be removed. The two lines can be combined like `Cells.Rows.AutoFit` which can also be shortened to `Rows.AutoFit`. `Cells` is a collection of all Cells in the sheet, so `Cells.Rows` is a collection of all Rows on the sheet which is the same as just `Rows`. So to conclude my side note: The lines can be shortened to `Rows.AutoFit`